# Matlab2Tikz Error with userdefined matlab colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab, matlab2tikz

I try to include from matlab exported (matlab2tikz) tikz files into latex, but get error messages if i don't use matlab default colors. I don't get the problem?!
Thanks you guys in advance

## Error:

!Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
and
! Missing number treated as zero

## Latex:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
        \setlength\fheight{0.7\textwidth}
    \setlength\fwidth{0.9\textwidth}    
    \includegraphics{img/image1.tikz}
    \caption{Blabla}
    \label{fig:blabla}
\end{figure}
```

## TIKZ FILE

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.7 running on MATLAB 8.1.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2014, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% Minimal pgfplots version: 1.3
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\fwidth,
height=\fheight,
view={322.5}{30},
scale only axis,
xmin=-0.2,
xmax=1.2,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=-1,
ymax=1,
ymajorgrids,
zmin=-0.1,
zmax=1.5,
zmajorgrids,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left
]
\addplot3 [color=blue,solid]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.001 0.001   0.001\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!96!green,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.479697819765937 -1.66533453693767e-18   -0.00291092455504537\\
0.46967140529907    -1.72084568816899e-17   -0.00304749019655101\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!94!green,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.489715272722715 1.22124532708768e-17    -0.0027807983753805\\
0.479697819765937   -1.66533453693767e-18   -0.00291092455504537\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!92!green,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.49972270061696  1.99840144432529e-17    -0.00265670325886659\\
0.489715272722715   1.22124532708768e-17    -0.0027807983753805\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!90!green,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.509720409510899 2.66453525910038e-17    -0.00253825813233725\\
0.49972270061696    1.99840144432529e-17    -0.00265670325886659\\
};



...etc.




 \addplot3 [color=white!26!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.829795595454906 -0.105304898583202  1.38110200542629\\
0.819887002709082   -0.107828908692529  1.38122697033729\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!24!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.839625002204565 -0.102840751537362  1.38096723284625\\
0.829795595454906   -0.105304898583202  1.38110200542629\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!22!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.849338403333923 -0.100435918845974  1.38082311765581\\
0.839625002204565   -0.102840751537362  1.38096723284625\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!20!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.858894935151754 -0.0980874166907242 1.38067020233289\\
0.849338403333923   -0.100435918845974  1.38082311765581\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!18!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.868252379508359 -0.0957923868952757 1.38050895947337\\
0.858894935151754   -0.0980874166907242 1.38067020233289\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!16!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.877369369839138 -0.0935501070091226 1.38033968037477\\
0.868252379508359   -0.0957923868952757 1.38050895947337\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!1.400000e+01!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.886207753298735 -0.0913610489013081 1.38016252820557\\
0.877369369839138   -0.0935501070091226 1.38033968037477\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!12!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.894734885516806 -0.089226416250731  1.37997756748673\\
0.886207753298735   -0.0913610489013081 1.38016252820557\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!10!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.902923998583969 -0.0871451464648408 1.37978494412629\\
0.894734885516806   -0.089226416250731  1.37997756748673\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!8!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.910755941285036 -0.0851129457921532 1.37958495399157\\
0.902923998583969   -0.0871451464648408 1.37978494412629\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!6!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.918222014540111 -0.0831254886403127 1.37937794641879\\
0.910755941285036   -0.0851129457921532 1.37958495399157\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!4!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.9253245154501   -0.0811820599220048 1.37916419853541\\
0.918222014540111   -0.0831254886403127 1.37937794641879\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=white!2!red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.932071571122559 -0.0792840566576747 1.37894400837872\\
0.9253245154501 -0.0811820599220048 1.37916419853541\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.938471567465238 -0.0774304719790548 1.37871788704809\\
0.932071571122559   -0.0792840566576747 1.37894400837872\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=black,line width=4.0pt,mark size=6.5pt,only marks,mark=o,mark options={solid}]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.938471567465238 -0.0774304719790548 1.37871788704809\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=red,line width=2.0pt,mark size=6.5pt,only marks,mark=o,mark options={solid}]
 table[row sep=crcr] {0.938471567465238 -0.0774304719790548 1.37871788704809\\
};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! Inside of our editor, you can mark code lines and hit 'CTRL-K' to format them as "code example".

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a mismatch in the number format when providing colors.

The syntax `color=white!1.400000e+01!red` is unsupported by the `xcolor` package; it expects fixed point numbers in mixing expressions.

Changing it to `color=white!14!red` fixes the problem.